# Hypothesis Testing: condition to reject the null hypothesis

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Here is a question from a statistics textbook, the (c) question asks the condition to reject the null hypothesis. And the answer is to consider whether the probability for 3 or fewer people supporting the candidate is less than 5%. And my question is: why don't we just consider the probability for 3 people supporting the candidate and compare it to 5%, why using the probability for 3 or fewer people supporting the candidate? Thanks for any hints.

[image]

Comment: Imagine if you suspected that a coin favors heads, and you wanted to test this by tossing it 1,000 times.  If we let $M$ be the random number of tails that you get, and $m$ the actual number of tails observed, and you reject the null hypothesis if $P(M=m)<0.05$, then you will ***always*** reject the null hypothesis for any value of $m$, since any particular number of tails has a probability less than 5%.  In a hypothesis test, we check the probability of observing data as extreme or more extreme than what we observed, under the null hypothesis, so we would check $P(M \le m)<0.05$ instead.

Comment: @Joe I see. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: While it is indeed true under conventional hypothesis testing that you check the probability of observing data as extreme or more extreme than what was observed, this is not an uncontrovertial point. This is exactly one of the criticisms made to classical hypothesis testing. More on this issue (and many others) is covered in the book Cult of Statistical Significance from Ziliak and McCloskey - https://www.press.umich.edu/186351/cult_of_statistical_significance

Comment: @bluemaster Thanks.